# Launch programs whose path contains spaces

Tags: vbscript

I need to launch programs in my local system using VBScript. But I am having trouble with the syntax. This is what I am using right now -

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
objShell.Run("iexplore")
Set objShell = Nothing
```

The above code successfully launches IE. I want to launch other browsers. But, if I use -

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
objShell.Run("c:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe")
Set objShell = Nothing
```

it is throwing an error saying that the file or path was not found. I am not sure how the parameter inside the Run() function is taken - should I give the path to an EXE or should I give some DOS commands?!

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Try:-

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
objShell.Run("""c:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe""")
Set objShell = Nothing
```

Note the extra ""s in the string.  Since the path to the exe contains spaces it needs to be contained with in quotes.  (In this case simply using "firefox.exe" would work).

Also bear in mind that many programs exist in the c:\Program Files (x86) folder on 64 bit versions of Windows.

Comment: Hi, thanks! I got confused with the quotes :D

But one note - using simply "firefox.exe" didn't work.

Comment: you can use `objShell.Run("""%ProgramFiles%\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe""")` to get round the 64-bit problem

Comment: Not really Jack. Firefox might still be installed under %ProgramFiles(x86)%.

Comment: In the event you want to pass parameters to the exe, do not include them within the `"""` on the path, do the following: `objShell.Run("""c:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe""" & " -p1 someValue")`

Answer (score 3):

You van use Exec

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
objShell.Exec("c:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe")
Set objShell = Nothing
```

Comment: This answer is identical to the above one, except it is slightly wrong because it doesn't include the double quotes around the program name.

Comment: This answer is nearly identical to the above one, except it eliminates the need for several quotes, and it does work.

Comment: Although, Exec is not allowed to start programs from C:\Users\user\Appdata\Local, whereas Run can start apps from there. (TeamSpeak 3 installs there, for me at least it did)

Answer (score 3):

```
set shell=CreateObject("Shell.Application")
' shell.ShellExecute "application", "arguments", "path", "verb", window
shell.ShellExecute  "slipery.bat",,"C:\Users\anthony\Desktop\dvx", "runas", 1
set shell=nothing
```

Answer (score 2):

It's working with

```
Set WSHELL = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
WSHELL.Exec("Application_Path")
```

But what should be the parameter in case we want to enter the application name only

e.g in case of Internet Explorer

```
WSHELL.Run("iexplore")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run("firefox")
Set objShell = Nothing
```

Please try this

Comment: It is not typed as i intended to. just messed up alignment. there is similar answer on the page with proper indenting.

Answer (score 1):

find an .exe file for the application you want to run 
example iexplore.exe and firefox.exe and remove .exe
and use it in objShell.Run("firefox")

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -10):

Copy the folder, firefox.exe is in and place in the c:\ only. The script is having a hard time climbing your file tree. I found that when I placed the *.exe file in the c:\ it eliminated the error message " file not found."

Comment: Not a very useful sokution to put everything in the FS root.

Comment: That solution cries for a whole bunch of other problems. Imagine you do this with two programs, both containing a file called `common.dll`.