# VB script want to run .bat file from VB

Tags: vbscript

I am try to run the **go.bat** from VB but when I run the script I get: :**cant find specific file**

but from the cmd window the file go.bat exist. what the problem?

```
Dim MyShell

Dim shell_cmd

  shell_cmd = "C:\Program Files\dir1\dir2\wizard\go.bat"

  set MyShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

  MyShell.Run shell_cmd, 1, 1
```

**from cmd window**

```
C:\Program Files\dir1\dir2\wizard>go.bat
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Launch programs whose path contains spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340355/launch-programs-whose-path-contains-spaces)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your batch file's full path contains spaces, so you need to enclose it in double quotes, like this:

```
shell_cmd = """C:\Program Files\dir1\dir2\wizard\go.bat"""
```

or

```
shell_cmd = Chr(34) & "C:\Program Files\dir1\dir2\wizard\go.bat" & Chr(34)
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you knew but in vb you can use the `Shell` function:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe736fyk(VS.71).aspx

(seems easier than what you're using)

I don't know why you get this message, but the two paths you mention are in fact different:

```
C:\Program Files\dir1\dir2\wizard\go.bat
C:\Program Files\dir1\dir2\wizard>go.bat
                                 ^
```

Comment: The second thing was from a command prompt window, apparently, according to the question, so the working directory was `C:\Program Files\dir1\dir2\wizard` and they were executing `go.bat` from there.

Comment: no they are the same 
C:\Program Files\dir1\dir2\wizard>go.bat 
go.bat is under wizard directory