# Call Batch file (multiple command lines to get the output) from VBS

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I am trying to write a VBscript to call a batch file.
Something what I am able to do from Command prompt but i failed to do the same from VBscript.
From cmd:

```
C:\PR\PS\build\bin>execDl.bat Jack > History.txt \n 
Jack> getHistory 50008 Dl \n
quit
```

I could call the 1st step from the script but i fail to understand how to do the 2nd and third step. till now my script

```
dim shell
dim ID 
ID ="50008"
dim Deal 
Deal ="Deal"
dim UserName 
Deal ="admin"
dim OutputPoint 
OutputPoint =">"
dim batchFileFolder
batchFileFolder = "C:\PR\PS\build\bin\"
set shell=createobject("wscript.shell")
strRun = batchFileFolder & "execDl.bat admin " & OutputPoint _
   & batchFileFolder & "output1.txt" & """"
shell.run(strRun)
set shell=nothing
```

### Any help is highly appreciated.

c:\PR\PS\build\bin>execDl.bat admin ------> gives out below output in command prompt   and then the cursor points to admin
Current User is: tswan

---

Welcome to FlowEngine Prototype command line interface.   
 For a listing of valid commands, (enter "help" at prompt.

---

admin> getHistory 7006 Dl

Activity History for Document: 7006

Process submitted on:  2010-05-19 00:55:59.56
Process id: 3
Submitter: swang

Activity Name                  Resource             Action               Completion Date                  Comments

---

Submit                         tswan                Submit               2010-05-19 00:55:59.937
Deal Manager                   tswan                Approve              2010-05-19 00:56:26.013
Approved                                            Completed            2010-05-19 00:56:26.027

getHistory "7006 Dl" has been successfully completed.

---

this is the overall sequence of commands I follow in command prompt and the one i have mentioned at the top is the three step command to redirect output to the text file.

My doubt is how do i execute the rest of the step that includes getHistory and the quit statement from vb script.
:(
@Mr Fuzzy Button Thanks for formatting it. I am new to stackoverflow way of posting.

Thanks

Comment: "@Mogsdad" let me know if you could help me in this. Thanks

Comment: I wonder if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2987959/1677912) helps.

Comment: Your script at present runs `execdeal.bat admin` and the output from that batch ends up in output1.txt - what more do you need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you need to get the commands you would normally type at the FlowEngine prompt into a file and then redirect standard input from this file.  Something like:

```
dim fso
dim f
dim cmd
dim shell
dim inpFile
dim outFile
inpFile = "execInput.txt"
outFile = "execOutput.txt"
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile( inpFile , 2, True)
f.Write "getHistory 50008 Deal" & vbCrLf & "quit" & vbCrLf
f.close
set shell=createobject("wscript.shell")
cmd = "execDeal.bat admin < " & inpFile & " > " & outFile
shell.run( cmd )
set shell=nothing
```