# Simple VBScript to open a application not working

Tags: vbscript

here is my VBScript

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "C:\Program Files\TrueCrypt\TrueCrypt.exe", 0 , false
```

It says it can't find it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [VBScript problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156903/vbscript-problem)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Launch programs whose path contains spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340355/launch-programs-whose-path-contains-spaces)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156903/vbscript-problem)

You can get around this by surrounding the path in quotes. But to do so, you need to escape them correctly(with "), so:

```
WshShell.Run """C:\Program Files\TrueCrypt\TrueCrypt.exe"""
```

Comment: This gives error. `Cannot use parenthesis while calling a sub`

Comment: Ok, got that working, but my code tells to open the application hidden, but not in windows vista

Comment: Will you plz elaborate ? Second Argument has a control over hidden attribute . Do you want no hide behaviour for vista?

Comment: Here is the question referring to the problem > [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857308/run-any-application-in-background)

Answer (score 0):

Either put more quotes around the path, or use the old style string for "Program Files" - Progra~1.

The following example works on my machine:

```
<package>
    <job id="truecrypt">
        <script language="VBScript">
            set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
            WshShell.Run """C:\Program Files\TrueCrypt\TrueCrypt.exe""", 0 , false
        </script>
    </job>
</package>
```

Comment: Would you take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857308/run-any-application-in-background) too

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
    Dim objShell
    Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
    objShell.Run("""C:\Program Files\TrueCrypt\TrueCrypt.exe""")
    Set objShell = Nothing
```

Comment: please remove the the spurious () in the .Run call.