# how to hide cmd from appearing at the back of your .vbs application?

Tags: windows, vbscript, cmd, exe

I am new to building apps using simple .vbs coding, whenever I build a .exe file using visual basic script command prompt opens along with the application at the background. so how to hide the command prompt from appearing??
and also how to set a background image in a pop up or input box?

Comment: Maybe this is what you're looking for.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857308/run-any-application-in-background

I think it might come in useful, as it speaks to run applications in the background.

Answer (score 0):

To your first question, it depends on how you are calling the vbs. Windows allow to execute tasks with hidden windows. If you can not create a hidden window and you doesn't need the console, instead of using cscript as the executable for the vbs, use wscript.

Popup and input box from vbscript are standard elements of the system. AFAIK no way of change background of them.