# VBScript pass commandline argument in paths with spaces

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to use VBS shell.run to run nircmd program with a script argument. For example,
this works:

```
objShell.Run """D:\App Run\NirCmd\nircmd.exe""script D:\testfolder\test.txt"
```

However if there are any spaces in the argument path it does not work and I have tried double quotes on the argument path with no luck. This does not work: (space in argument)

```
objShell.Run """D:\App Run\NirCmd\nircmd.exe""script D:\test folder\test.txt"
```

I need the ability to have spaces in the argument path. thanks for any help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Launch programs whose path contains spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340355/launch-programs-whose-path-contains-spaces)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
objShell.Run """D:\App Run\NirCmd\nircmd.exe"" script ""D:\test folder\test.txt"""
```