# Start executable with ini file in VB?

Tags: vbscript

Im trying to start an executable with an Ini file.
We need this, so we can start lotus notes as the ini files is needed for the datapath.
The shortcut is `notes.exe =h:\lotus\notes\notes.ini`.

I tried the following script

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.shell") 
objShell.run "%comspec% /c "C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Lotus\Notes\notes.exe"   
=h:\lotus\notes\notes.ini
```

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Launch programs whose path contains spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340355/launch-programs-whose-path-contains-spaces)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%COMSPEC%` is not required, but you need double quotes around the program path (because it contains spaces), and you must escape them (by prepending them with another double qoute), because they're inside a string. Without escaping you get a string `"%comspec% /c "` followed by an invalid "operator" `C:\Program` and other garbage.

Change this:

```
objShell.run "%comspec% /c "C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Lotus\Notes\notes.exe" =h:\lotus\notes\notes.ini
```

into this:

```
objShell.run """C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Lotus\Notes\notes.exe"" =h:\lotus\notes\notes.ini"
```

and the problem should disappear.