# How to run java program via vbscript with multiple arguments?

Tags: java, vbscript, executable-jar

I want to run a simple java programme with parsing arguments using VB Scripts.

this is my VBScript code

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim jar
Dim location
Dim dictionary
Set dictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
jar = "C:\Users\Documents\ExP.jar"
location = "C:\Users\Documents\TestProject"
Set WshShellExec = WshShell.Exec("java -jar " & Chr(34) & jar & Chr(34) & location & Chr(34))
End Sub
```

This is my java class which I want to pass arguments

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ReadTestScripts readTestScripts = new ReadTestScripts(args[3]);
//location  ="C:\\Users\\Documents\\TestProject" - want to pass this path to java programme 
        readTestScripts.showResult();
    }
```

I didn't get the expected output when I pass the location as VBScript argument

Comment: You have no spaces between your arguments. Also, don't use `Chr(34)` it's very jarring instead escape the double-quote by doubling it, example `jar = """C:\Users\Documents\ExP.jarr"""`. Your raw java command in a VBScript string should look something like `"java -jar ""C:\Users\Documents\ExP.jar"" ""C:\Users\Documents\TestProject"""`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are concatenating the command to execute but not leaving spaces between the arguments so at the moment if you debugged the command being passed to `Exec()` it will look like;

```
java -jar "C:\Users\Documents\ExP.jar""C:\Users\Documents\TestProject"
```

The fix is to add a concatentated space between `jar` and `location`.

```vb
Sub Button1_Click()
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Dim a
    Dim location
    Dim dictionary
    Set dictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    jar = "C:\Users\Documents\ExP.jar"
    location = "C:\Users\Documents\TestProject"
    Set WshShellExec = WshShell.Exec("java -jar """ & jar & """ """ & location & """")
End Sub
```

Which will produce the command

```
java -jar "C:\Users\Documents\ExP.jar" "C:\Users\Documents\TestProject"
```

Note, the replacement of `Chr(34)` with the correct escape method for double quotes which is to double them.

---

#### Useful Links

- [Launch programs whose path contains spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1340355/692942)

Comment: can we use  `Space(number)` syntax for the spaces

Comment: You absolutely could but for what purpose when `" "` would  suffice?